# STL map memory not being cleared

Tags: c++, stl

A structure like -

```
std::unordered_map <unsigned int, std::tuple<float, float, Data> >  testMap;
```

where Data is -

```
class Data
{
   std::string a;
   std::string b;
   std::string c;
   std::string d;
   std::string e;
}
```

is initially populated with about 65 million records.

Here is an example of how the elements are inserted into the map -

```
unsigned int i = 10002;
float f1 = 2.0f, f2 = 3.0f; 
Data data; 
data.a = "ValueA";
data.b = "ValueB";
data.c = "ValueC";

testMap[i] = std::make_tuple(f1, f2, data);
```

At this point, the system shows -

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           29G        29G       200M       3.2G       5.4M       4.4G
-/+ buffers/cache:        14G       14.6G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Then an event is raised that causes the program to clear() this map and reload it.

After the reload, the numbers are -

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           29G        29G       200M       3.2G       5.4M       4.4G
-/+ buffers/cache:        24G       4.6G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

This seems to indicate that the clear() did not actually free the memory.

Is this a reasonable assessment and if so, what is the right approach to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you make assignments to this map? I'm wondering if your pairs are still in memory maybe